# How to remove object property from an array of objects if the value is 0

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I have an array like this:

```
const data = [
  { percent: 123, unit: -1 },
  { percent: 456, unit: 0 },
  { percent: 0, unit: 5},
  { percent: 789, unit: -3 }
];
```

and I'm trying to remove all properties that have 0 value, so the desired result will be like this:

```
var data = [
  { percent: 123, unit: -1 },
  { percent: 456 },
  { unit: 5},
  { percent: 789, unit: -3 }
];
```

I've tried something like this:

```
const newData = 
   data.map(e => 
      Object.keys(e).forEach(key => 
         e[key] === 0 && delete e[key]));
```

but that returns an array of undefined values.

```js
const data = [
    { percent: 123, unit: -1 },
    { percent: 456, unit: 0 },
    { percent: 0, unit: 5},
    { percent: 789, unit: -3 }
];

const newData = data.map(e => Object.keys(e).forEach(key => e[key] === 0 && delete e[key]))

console.log(newData)
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can use simply `.filter` to select only desired items https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter In result you will get new array

Comment: Replace the first map with forEach as you’re not currently returning any data. Or return `e` after `Object.keys`?

Comment: @evolutionxbox, oh, got it

Comment: `newData = data.map(e => e.percent == 0 || e.unit == 0 ? {}: e)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) doesn't return an array.

To achieve your desired output, in each iteration, use [`Object#entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to get the key-value pairs of the current object, and [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to filter the ones where the `value` is zero. To construct the resulting object again, use [`Object#fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries):

```js
const data = [ { percent: 123, unit: -1 }, { percent: 456, unit: 0 }, { percent: 0, unit: 5}, { percent: 789, unit: -3 } ];

const newData = data.map(e => 
  Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(e).filter(([key, value]) => value !== 0)
  )
);

console.log(newData)
```

Answer (score 1):

It is all undefined because you are not returning anything from the method inside `data.map`.

You can use Array reduce method to solve this problem.

```js
const data = [
    { percent: 123, unit: -1 },
    { percent: 456, unit: 0 },
    { percent: 0, unit: 5},
    { percent: 789, unit: -3 }
];

const newData = data.map(e => {
  const newObj = Object.keys(e).reduce((prev, curr) => {
    if(e[curr] !== 0) prev[curr] = e[curr];
    return prev;
  }, {});
  return newObj;
})

console.log(newData)
```